# Expanding Sticky sidebar with fixed position: push down content, how

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar I want sticky when its hits the header - so I wrote a script that gives it a fixed class when scroll reaches correct position, then gave it a fixed position. Sp far so good- But the sidebar has an expanding column, and being fixed this expandes the sidebar down and out of the page.

How can I make it stick but still push content down?

Comment: in your JS, where you gave fixed position to sidebar, add width too which only take effect when page scroll so side bar won't expand out of page width

Comment: How about some code?

Comment: It expands down - not on the side and already have a width. @Shehary

Comment: @Xeptor without code or fiddle, only can guess the solution

Comment: Sorry but the code is live on a test site thats password protected. All I wanted to now if I can make an element sticky without a fixed position. Its to much code to re-create in a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it using pure css because:

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
>   viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
>   page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
>   to position the element.
>
> A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would
>   normally have been located.

So it is out of the document's flow **but** you can use js to achieve what you want like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#expander').click(function () {
        $('.content').toggleClass('nav-expanded');
    })
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100%;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    padding: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: .35s;
}
.nav-expanded {
    padding-top: 165px;  /*you can change the value to more accuracy */
}

.navbar-ex1-collapse{
    width: 100%;
}

.list-group .list-group-item{
    background: #f8f8f8 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="header"> 
        <a href="#">Logotipo</a>

        <button id="expander" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Enlace #1</a>

                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Enlace #2</a>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>w</p>
    <p>e</p>
    <p>r</p>
    <p>t</p>
    <p>y</p>
    <p>u</p>
    <p>i</p>
    <p>o</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>s</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>f</p>
    <p>g</p>
    <p>h</p>
    <p>j</p>
    <p>k</p>
    <p>l</p>
    <p>z</p>
    <p>x</p>
</div>
```

The idea is when you `click` the button to expand the header(or whatever you use for that) setting `padding-top` on `content` equal to the `height` of you header expanded. You even can compute the height of `navbar` in js using `.outerheight()` and setting that height as `padding-top` of `.content` to make it more accuracy, the use of important in snippet is only because the bootstrap's styles overwrite mines but in general that is not needed.

I hope you get the idea so you may use it.